# RL problem on COLAB for 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'LunarLander'

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

What can I do in Colab to work with the env "LunarLander-v2" from OPENAI-gym. I have installed **BOX2D** and **box2d-py** but always return the same error:

```
AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'LunarLander'
```

This passage in my local machine works, but on Colab not.
What could be a solution ?

Versions:
Python:3.6    -   Gym:0.17.2      -     BOX2D:2.3.10

Comment: Can you show us the command line how you want to run the env?

Comment: @constanze, I have solved the problem in this way: 1) Downloading swig directory [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/swig/) 2) extract swig.exe 3) Put swig.exe into the wd of Jupyter notebook in Colab (**content** folder in my case) 4) !pip install BOX2D . Finally Lunar lander works. Did you have another way ?

Answer (score 8):

Important part is to create a new Colab notebook, Click on File -> New notebook. On a new (fresh) Colab execute these:

```py
!pip3 install box2d-py
!pip3 install gym[Box_2D]
import gym
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2")
```

The gym is installed by default in the new notebook however you have to install the box2d-py and gym[Box_2D]. Please close the current notebook if you have encountered the  `'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'LunarLander'` error. Simply use a new notebook and go on with above procedure of pip install. It will work!

Comment: Hi! Please run the commands one by one. Also, please paste the error if any?

Comment: Terminating the session in colab after seeing the error and then Reconnecting does indeed work (after running the above).

Answer (score 3):

```
%pip install ribs[all] gym~=0.17.0 Box2D~=2.3.10 tqdm
import gym
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2")
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

Just installing Box2D solved the issue for me

```
pip install Box2D
```

Comment: It's important to run `pip install Box2D` BEFORE the first call to `gym.make("LunarLander-v2")`. If you already received this error:`'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'LunarLander'` then you need to factory reset runtime (Runtime -> Factory reset runtime) or create a new notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from the absence of `pybox2d` package. Colab or not, does not matter.

The error will appear for any 2d continuous environment.

Install `pybox2d` by using `conda install -c conda-forge pybox2d` if you are using Anaconda or by using `pip install Box2D` if you like **pip**.

Good luck.